# xxhash64 implemented in javascript

Tags: javascript, hash, hex

Most, if not all, xxhash implementations for javascript produce UINT32 as digest.

Is there any implementation of xxhash in javascript that produces digest as hexadecimal representation of 64bit unsigned int from variable length string input?

Comment: [js-xxhash](https://github.com/pierrec/js-xxhash) now supports it through `XXH.h64`.